# "Filename or extension is too long" error when setting account for Windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I've created a windows service application in C#. I'm trying to run the service using a "Managed Service Account" on Windows Server 2012. The problem is, I cannot set the account the service should run as. When I set service's properties I get an error "The filename or extension is too long." Google search didn't help a bit, it seems like no one else faced this kind of problem.

Here are some details of what I did:

1) created the service application in Visual Studio 2012. The service is in a namespace so the executable name looks more or less like Name1.Name2.ServiceName.exe

2) installed the service on the machine where it's suppose to run without problems (using installutil.exe)

3) created "Managed Service Account" in the Active Directory domain following the steps from this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6i4j0O3suNk. In short, it uses Active Directory module for Windows Power Shell. In Power Shell (ran as Administrator) I needed to execute the following commands:

```
import-module ActiveDirectory
New-ADServiceAccount -name ServiceAccountName -enable $true
Add-ADComputerServiceAccount -Identity HostName -ServiceAccount ServiceAccountName
```

on HostName host (where I want to run the service) I needed to run also

```
Install-ADServiceAccount -Identity ServiceAccountName
```

Everything went smoothly up to this point

4) In Administrative Tools -> Services in my service's properties, on "Log On" tab I select "This account" and search for ServiceAccountName. It finds it alright, but when I try to click OK it tells me to enter a valid password. Now AFAIK the password should stay empty for Managed Service Account, so I erase it, and then pressing OK gives me this meaningless error "The filename or extension is too long."

5) I also added this account in Administrative Tools -> Local Security Policy -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment -> Log on as a service but the result is the same.

I'd like to do it the "Windows Server 2012" way without creating a regular user account for the service but I have no idea why this error pops up. Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I resolved it by creating another account with shorter name... Seems like an AD bug, but maybe someone will find it helpful if facing same issue.